# Apache reverse proxy configuration ignored

Tags: apache

I have multiple instances of apache running, one instance per developer with multiple vhosts each (one for each project) and I'm trying to setup a reverse proxy, since it's quite inconvenient to access through IP address, all on one server;

The static DNS entries on the GW (simplified):

```
project1.john.test A <server_ip>
project2.john.test A <server_ip>
```

The per developer vhost config file

```
<VirtualHost *:11010>
    ServerName project1.john.test
    DocumentRoot <path_to_html>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project1.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project1.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:11010>
    ServerName project2.john.test
    DocumentRoot <path_to_html>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project2.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project2.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The reverse proxy config file

```
<VitualHost *:80>
ProxyPass "http://project1.john.test/" "http://127.0.0.1:11010/"
ProxyPassReverse "http://project1.john.test/" "http://127.0.0.1:11010/"
ProxyPass "http://project2.john.test/" "http://127.0.0.1:11010/"
ProxyPassReverse "http://project2.john.test/" "http://127.0.0.1:11010/"
</virtualHost>
```

Now whenever I try to access project1.john.test, the default www page shows up, the only change in the logs is in the proxy instance's other_vhosts_access.log, that's the only activity I could find.

What have I missed/misconfigured?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't need a reverse proxy config. Just the name-based virtual hosts should be enough: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: I like to keep the instances separate, if someone new was to come into the team, they could have their own apache instance hosting their code to be worked on without affecting other people's workflow.

Your comment suggests having all the vhosts in a single instance? Am I correct?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by 'separate'. I suppose you could run multiple apache servers on a single machine, and have each developer manage them individually. Or you can run a single apache server with separate config for each developer. In any case, you'd need to either run the hosts on separate ports, or have different 'contexts' to distinguish the separate developers. I don't think the reverse proxy config will work with hostnames alone.